# optimise api calls rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an array , and i want to loop through the array and call server data on each item . I want to show a spinner as api is being in pending state as i load the page.

Current solution:

```
  getRecordings(classroom) {
    return this.sysAdminService.getMeetingRecordings(classroom.meeting_id).subscribe(res => {
      classroom.recordings = res;
    });
  }
```

Api calls:

```
 this.classRoomsToDisplay.map((classroom) => {
      classroom.showAttendees = false;
      classroom.recordings = null;
      this.getRecordings(classroom);
    });
```

As above im subscribing to the observable for each item in an array .I want to find if there is any better way to do this using rxjs , concatMap? i dont want to wait for the api calls for the entire array to be completed , i want to display the result as soon as the api call for that item is completed.

Comment: maybe forkJoin can help? https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin

Comment: fork join will wait for all observables to complete right? @Clashsoft . i dont want to wait for all observables. i want to get result as soon as its completed for an item and proceed to next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the data you've shown, it isn't clear which property you're using to display the data. I'll assume it's `classroom.showAttendees` since it's a boolean.

You could use RxJS `forkJoin` function to combine multiple observables and subscribe once instead of having multiple subscriptions. And you could toggle the `showAttendees` flag for each item in the array as a side-effect using `tap` operator.

Try the following

```js
complete$ = new Subject<any>();

getRecordings(classroom): Observable<any> {   // <-- return the HTTP request observable
  return this.sysAdminService.getMeetingRecordings(classroom.meeting_id).pipe(
    tap => {
      classroom.showAttendees = true;         // <-- set the flag to show data
      classroom.recordings = res;
    }
  );
}

ngOnInit() {
  // `reqs` is an array of observables `[getRecordings(classroom), getRecordings(classroom), ...]`
  const reqs = this.classRoomsToDisplay.map((classroom) => {
    classroom.showAttendees = false;
    classroom.recordings = null;
    return this.getRecordings(classroom);
  });

  forkJoin(reqs).pipe(takeUntil(this.complete$)).subscribe();   // <-- trigger the HTTP requests
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.complete$.next();        // <-- close open subscriptions
}
```

Template

```html
<div *ngFor="classroom of classRoomsToDisplay">
  <ng-container *ngIf="classroom.showAttendees">
    {{ classroom.recordings }}
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Now since we're assigning the values in the `tap` operator, data for each item will be shown as soon as they arrive.

Answer (score 1):

You should prefer using the async pipe instead of the subscription.

Example:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let attendee of attendeesWithData">Attendee: {{ attendee.attendee }}, duplicated: {{ (attendee.duplication | async) || 'pending' }}</li>
</ul>
```

In this example the async operation is a duplication of the string and the request takes longer each time for demonstration.

```
@Injectable()
export class DuplicateService {

  times = 1;

  constructor() { }

  getDuplicated(s: string): Observable<string> {
    return timer(1000 * this.times++).pipe(
      map(() => s + s),
    );
  }
}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  private attendees: string[] = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];

  attendeesWithData = this.attendees.map(attendee => ({ 
    attendee,
    duplication: this.duplicateService.getDuplicated(attendee),
  }));

  constructor(private duplicateService: DuplicateService) {}
}
```

As a result each second one list item switches its state from pending to the duplicated string.

See also the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rtx6cg?file=src/app/app.component.ts